# Can not play video uploaded from android to php server

Tags: php, android, video

I have uploaded mp4 video captured by emulator to php server, but i can not play this uploaded video with any player(window media player, vlc etc).

when i extracted this vidoe from emulator using file explorer, it is playing with vlc media player.

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            DataInputStream inputStream = null;
            String urlServer = "http://10.0.2.2:80/maria/upload_file2.php";
            String pathToOurFile="/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150225_152244.mp4";


            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "123*****sdf";

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

                URL url = new URL(urlServer);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs & Outputs
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Enable POST method
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=123*****sdf");

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile );
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                Log.d("ServerCode",""+serverResponseCode);
                Log.d("serverResponseMessage",""+serverResponseMessage);
                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

                       return "Success";

        }
```

php code on server side.

```
$targetfolder = "images/";

$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) ;




if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

 {

 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " is uploaded";

 }

 else {

 echo "Problem uploading file";

 }
```

i have tested php code by uploading video from html form , this video is playing fine, i think there is problem with android code. can someone help me to find problem in code.

Comment: If you look for a code to upload files from Android to PHP that actually works, this is the one. Thanks

Comment: My problem resolved by setting this line dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploadedfile';filename='" + selectedPath + "'" + lineEnd);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While uploading videos on php server keep every video name and its direct mp4 url in your database. For example in your php code you are uploading your videos in your image folder of your server. if your video name is "myvideo" then its url will be http://your-domain-name.com/images/myvideo.mp4. save those links in your database and make web service to get all video links. call that web service from android and use android videoview to play that video. here is the xml of videoview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the code to play video and there is no need of asynctask to play video in android. videoview will stream it.

```
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(" http://your-domain-name.com/images/myvideo.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                videoView.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i mean this video playing fine on android emulator, but when i upload this on server using  httpurlconnection class. i can not play this video on server using any media player. there is problem with android code which upload video ,can you check this code. if you have your code to upload video ,plz share with me.

Comment: please verify that your video is being successfully uploaded or share your uploaded video url with me.

Comment: yes i can see video on server but can not share it's url as i am uploading this on local web server on my laptop, did you find any error in my code ?

Comment: if you can see uploaded video with same length then your code is righ and there could be the localhost permissions issue to android. You must try free php server. here is link (https://byethost.com/index.php/free-hosting) make your account and domain for free here. upload your video and share its url or folder with me.

Comment: bro , i have uploaded on this url, it is not working http://isb.nu.edu.pk/nusoap/maria/video/